# Passing emit events to a global modal window VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pinia

When i started this project a created a reusable global window component using a Pinia store. It has worked beautifully for me and I haven't had any problems with it while working on the project for 2 months. All of my modals have been forms that don't need acces to any outside reactive varaibles.

The problem:

I need a way to extend my component in a way so it can handle Vue event emits. This way the component is able to communicate to outside components.

#### The current component and its Pinia store:

```js
import { defineStore } from "pinia";
import { ref } from "vue";
import { markRaw } from "vue";

const defaultState = { component: null, props: {} };

export const useModalStore = defineStore("modal", () => {
  const modalState = ref(defaultState);

  const openModal = ({ component, props }) => {
    modalState.value = { component: markRaw(component), props: props || {} };
  };

  const closeModal = () => {
    modalState.value = defaultState;
  };

  return { modalState, openModal, closeModal };
});
```

```js
<script setup>
import { useModalStore } from "@stores/ModalStore";
import { storeToRefs } from "pinia";

const { closeModal } = useModalStore();
const { modalState } = storeToRefs(useModalStore());
</script>

<template>
  <Teleport to="#modals">
    <Transition name="modal-window-transition">
      <div
        class="modal-window__wrapper"
        @click.self="closeModal"
        v-if="modalState?.component"
      >
        <div class="modal-window">
          <component :is="modalState?.component" v-bind="modalState?.props" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </Transition>
  </Teleport>
</template>
```

#### How is the component used?

First import the modalStore and the component u want in the modal. Then extract the openModal and or closeModal actions from the store. Call the appropriate action when for example a click event occours. You can pass props just fine using the props param.

```js
import { useModalStore } from "@stores/ModalStore";

import BaseButton from "@components/BaseButton.vue";
import DishesModalCreate from "@components/DishesModalCreate.vue";

<BaseButton @click="openModal({ component: DishesModalCreate })"
  >Add dish
</BaseButton>
```

I'll try to explain the problem I want to solve using an example. How can the ModalContent component update the parentValue ref trough an event.

###### Parent.vue

```js
import { useModalStore } from "@stores/ModalStore";
import { ref } from "vue"

import ModalContent from "@components/ModalContent.vue";

const { openModal } = useModalStore();

const parentValue = ref("update me via modal")

<template>
  <button @click="openModal({component: ModalContent})"></button>
</template>
```

###### ModalContent.vue

```js
<script setup>
const emits = defineEmits(['updateParentState'])
</script>

<template>
  <button @click="emit("updateParentState")"></button>
</template>
```

#### Possible solutions

I know you can pass functions as props in Vue but its considered as a bad practice that if possible I want to avoid.

Another option would be to use global state but That's a bit overkill imo.

Hope this gives enough context to understand what I'm trying to achieve. Any insights are welcome thanks in advance!!

Comment: It's normal to pass callback functions where necessary, even without using vue events. In fact, `on...` props are processed as `...` event listeners on low level, i.e. you can pass `onUpdateParentState` and expect that it will be called on emit("updateParentState")

Comment: So i can get rid of the emit event all together and just pass the function down as a prop like u do in React ?

Comment: You can, but here you can still use emit because it's workable with the said prop name convention, at least in vue 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to pass callbacks through props where necessary in Vue but here event bus still can be used. Event listeners can be passed altogether with `v-bind`, their names are universally processed to match to the convention used in [render functions](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/render-function.html#v-on); `onFoo` prop is processed the same way as `@foo` event handler.

```
openModal({ component: ModalContent, props: { onUpdateParentState: someFn } })
```

Where `someFn` is supposed to be triggered on `emit("updateParentState")` inside `ModalContent`

Answer (score 0):

For my use case i wanted to update the contents of a delivery so i passed the onUpdateOutboundDeliveryContents prop to my modal that triggers the updateOutboundDeliveryContents function in the parent component. In the modal itself I defined the event and then emit it when a button is clicked.

Thanks for the help and if there is something I misunderstood you can definetly let me know!

```js
const emits = defineEmits(["updateOutboundDeliveryContents"]);

<BaseButton
  @click="$emit('updateOutboundDeliveryContents')"
  >Add to outbound delivery
</BaseButton>

props: {
  machine: machine,
  onUpdateOutboundDeliveryContents: updateOutboundDeliveryContents,
},

const updateOutboundDeliveryContents = (content) => {
  console.log("updating...");
};
```